# GHC 6.12 and MacPorts

Tags: macos, haskell, libraries, ghc, conflicting-libraries

I recently installed (from the binary installers) GHC 6.12 and the [Haskell Platform 2010.1.0.1](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/mac.html) on my Intel MacBook running OS X 10.5.8, and initially, everything worked fine.  *Edit:* I had to install `cabal`, `alex`, and `happy` from source, but after *that*, everything did seem to work fine.  However, I discovered that if I use `cabal install` to install a package which depends on a MacPorts library (*e.g.*, `cabal install --extra-lib-dirs=/opt/local/lib --extra-include-dirs=/opt/local/include gd`), things work fine in GHCi, but if I try to compile, I get the error

```
Linking test ...
Undefined symbols:
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _hs_iconv_close in libHSbase-4.2.0.0.a(iconv.o)
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _hs_iconv in libHSbase-4.2.0.0.a(iconv.o)
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _hs_iconv_open in libHSbase-4.2.0.0.a(iconv.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

After some Googling, I found [a long Haskell-cafe thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg69120.html) discussing this problem.  The upshot seems to be that [MacPorts installs an updated version of libiconv](http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg69139.html), and the binary interface is slightly different from the version included with the system.  Consequently, if you try to link with any MacPorts library, the MacPorts libiconv gets linked in too; and since the base library was built to link against a different version of libiconv, things break.  I've tried [setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`](http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg69179.html) and adding more flags to try to get it to look at `/usr/lib` again (*e.g.* `cabal install --extra-lib-dirs=/opt/local/lib --extra-include-dirs=/opt/local/include --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/lib --extra-include-dirs=/usr/include gd`), but neither worked.  Uninstalling the MacPorts `libiconv` isn't really an option, since I have a bunch of ports installed which depend on it---including some ports I want Haskell to link to, like `gd2`.

From what I've seen online, the upshot really seems to be "you're boned": you cannot link against any MacPorts library while compiling with GHC, and there doesn't seem to be a solution.  However, that thread was from the end of 2009, so I figure there's a chance that someone has a solution, workaround, ridiculous hack… anything, really.  So: **does anybody know how to get GHC 6.12 to link against the system libiconv at the same time as it links to libraries from MacPorts?**  Or, failing that, a way to make linking *not break* in some other clever way?

Comment: Did you install the binary Haskell Platform, or the MacPorts build? Or the source build?

Comment: Binary installers for both GHC and the Haskell Platform.  I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: I'm getting exactly this problem with a GHC 6.12.3 I've built from source.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was getting the same error on MacOSX 10.5.8 when I installed haskell-platform-2010.1.0.1-i386 and attempted to compile a haskell program.  The solution for me was to add the option "-L/usr/lib" to ghc when compiling the program.  I believe this managed to get the linker to first search /usr/lib for the iconv library which resolved the problem for me.

Comment: I could have sworn I'd tried this, but when I was compiling something using GTK today and getting the same error, I thought I'd give it a shot.  Lo and behold, it worked!  Thank you!

Comment: How do you accomplish this when installing things with cabal ?

Comment: A simple "extra-lib-dirs: /usr/lib" in ~/.cabal/config took care of that for me.

Answer (score 1):

I made my problems go away by uninstalling MacPorts. You could probably get away with just uninstalling the MacPorts version of libiconv and any library that depends on it.

Comment: This worked for me as well. HomeBrew seems to be a good alternative to MacPorts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm somewhat ashamed to admit this, but I've had some success with incantations like the following:

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/opt/local/lib cabal install --ghc-option="-L/usr/lib" SDL-gfx
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed by :

```
stack build --ghc-options "-L/usr/lib"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is weird: [afaik Platform 2010.1.0.1 does not work on OS X 10.5.8](http://trac.haskell.org/haskell-platform/ticket/110#comment:2), this has been reported and verified by several people including myself, and more interestingly - [by you](http://trac.haskell.org/haskell-platform/ticket/110#comment:3)!

Comment: That bug indicates that *cabal* doesn't work---for me, at least, GHC and GHCi worked fine.  I had to install `cabal`, `alex`, and `happy` from source; once I did that, everything worked (except for this libiconv error).  Good catch, though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may be better 
  `cabal configure --extra-lib-dir=/usr/lib`
It does resolve the issue on OSX Mountain Lion